# problem on sending file to server in android..formated code

Tags: android

```
public class Sendfile extends Activity 
{

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);

String url = "http://http://192.168.0.158:4299";

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
    "sendingfile.txt");

try {
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
   InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
     new FileInputStream(file), -1);

reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");

reqEntity.setChunked(true);

// Send in multiple parts if needed

httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(),
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   // Do something with response...
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // show error
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: where is my crystal ball? I thought I had it over there.... (this is irony... I suggest you rethink your question... wait, there is none!)

Comment: i'm unable to send sendfile.txt to server..i'm not getting any exception and any response

Comment: Why did you delete 5 of your 7 questions? Didn't even bother to award anyone with any correct answers. And now you've created another question, which is almost identical to one of the many others you've created. You're a spammer and a leech... not even sure why you're not banned yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is that your URL is invalid; instead of "http://http://192.168.0.158:4299" it should read "http://192.168.0.158:4299". There may well be more problems in there as well, but that one leaps off the page.

The style of the code is pretty horrible as well. A large block of code that catches Exception is almost always bad. A large block of code that catches Exception and then ignores it is almost always worse.

Comment: You need to do something with that exception; this would let you see where the problem is. Add something like:

android.util.Log.d("reddy", "Problem making HTTP request", e);

into the catch block, then check the log to see what's failing to work.

Comment: in logacat i'm getting filenot found exception,problem in making http request..but i've added the file

Comment: Than I guess your txt file isn't where you look at?!

Comment: no..i've added the text file in application itself..next to res ..i just want to send tat file